# View observer on controller.model not working after 1.0.0rc8

Tags: ember.js

I have a text area that should receive focus when the model of its associated controller changes.

Prior to rc8, I used this observer:

```
modelChanged: function() {
  this.set('focusing', true);
  this.$().focus();
  this.set('focusing', false);
}.observes('controller.model'),
```

I can't get it to work in 1.0.0 release or rc8. I have verified that an observer in the controller fires when expected:

```
modelChanged: function() {
  console.log('TextArtController->modelChanged');
}.observes('model'),
```

However I would much refer not to have the controller at that level care about the specific view (I want pull not push)

---

After some more digging I discovered this change note:

- Make TextField and TextArea components

This severs my textarea subclass from the controller/view hierarchy.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the latest version of ember 1.0.0 the view's `TextField` & `TextArea` where converted to components `Ember.Component` and since components as isolated view's not knowing about it's context the `controller` property does not refer to the `controller` anymore.

Said that, a way you could still accomplish what you are trying to do would be to use the not documented `targetObject` which refers to the `controller` in the view's surrounding context.

```
modelChanged: function() {
  this.set('focusing', true);
  this.$().focus();
  this.set('focusing', false);
}.observes('targetObject.model'),
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: in the end I used a model property & binding, but it is very helpful to know about the targetObject